# Qual a origem do termo "pintar e bordar"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, origem

Geralmente uso o termo "pintar e bordar" para uma pessoa que faz algo, geralmente errado, extrapolando os limites.

No entanto qual seria a origem? O termo tem alguma relação com "pintar o sete"?

Answer (score 2):

Eu me limitaria a dizer que extrapola os limites. Um exemplo:

> "Outra seleção de muito carisma que pintou e bordou na Euro foi a
>   Islândia. A seleção do país que conta com pouco mais de 300 mil
>   habitantes fez história ao chegar até às quartas de final".

Retirado [daqui](http://esportes.r7.com/futebol/fotos/campeao-com-seis-empates-surpresas-e-will-griggs-on-fire-veja-o-que-de-mais-legal-rolou-na-euro-2016-12072016?foto=4#!/foto/4). Neste caso, a boa campanha não me parece algo errado. Mas, claro, notei o uso do termo *geralmente* na sua colocação.

Já o [Dicionário Informal](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=significado+pintar+e+bordar&oq=significado+pintar+e+bordar&aqs=chrome..69i57.2949j0j4&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) diz:

> Pintar e bordar é uma expressão popular que, de certa forma, retoma a
>   expressão PINTAR O SETE, a qual significa bagunçar, fazer o que não se
>   deve, passar dos limites.

O [Dicionário de Gírias](http://www.dicionariodegirias.com.br/pintar-e-bordar/) diz que é "Fazer bagunça", mas não menciona relação com "Pintar o sete".

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido essa expressão ates. Será possível que a expressão tenha origem de uma adulteração popular de "Pintar e **Borrar**"?

Comment: Não sei responder, nunca ouvi tal expressão!

Comment: Fazer arte, bagunçar, fazer o que dá na telha: "O menino pintou e bordou enquanto a mãe foi ao mercado", tomar atitudes fora da normalidade por conta própria: "ele está aproveitando as férias do chefe para pintar e bordar"